# How to set new data in the chart of Sencha touch

Tags: charts, sencha-touch-2

Hi I downloaded Sencha touch 2.1 and I used chart example code given in that to run it and it worked well. but as per my requirement I have to refresh the chart when User selects a year from picker. but I am not able to update the chart.

For 1st time to load data in chart, I have  used Store and but for next time I tried to set proxy parameter to my store and then set the store to chart, but my chart is not getting refreshed. my files are here. [view](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/73250761/Main.js)   [Store](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/73250761/MyStore.js) [Model](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/73250761/User.js)

Below is code which I am using to refresh the chart.

```
var myProxy = store.getProxy();                                                            
myProxy.setExtraParam( 'Year', '2010' );                                                                        
store.setProxy(myProxy);
var myChart = Ext.getCmp('myChart');                                           
myChart.setStore(store);                                                     
myChart.renderFrame();
```

Please help me.

Comment: was able to solve it.now chart is updating using below code var data = [];
            data.push
            (
             {"name": "Item-0", "comedy": 18.34}, 
             {"name": "Item-1", "comedy": 2.67}, 
            );
            store.setData(data);

Comment: Great! You should post your answer as the answer to your question and check mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve it. now chart is updating using below code

```
var data = []; 
data.push 
( 
    {"name": "Item-0", "comedy": 18.34}, 
    {"name": "Item-1", "comedy": 2.67}, 
); 
store.setData(data);
```

hope it will help someone.